# Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I read that Windows wp8 allows native code.  So how then have ports such as Angry birds been made to run on wp7. What's the difference?

Thanks!

Comment: the native code will allow many game engines and frameworks to be portable to windows phone platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, NDK was available and before WP8 but only for scpecial companies. With WP8 native code is available officially.

Second, XNA ?